# Swapping 2 nodes in a deque, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, swap, doubly-linked-list, deque

I am trying to swap two non-adjacent nodes. Also, they are not front or rear nodes such that their previous or next pointers are not None. Python doesn't have pointers, but I would refer to the previous & next references to nodes of a node as its pointers for convenience.
However, the problem I am having is that even though the switch is successful, the previous pointer references are messed up. Here, l is the left node, and r is the right node.

```
def _swap(self, l, r):
    assert l is not None and r is not None, "nodes to swap cannot be None"

    temp = l._prev._next
    l._prev._next = r._prev._next
    r._prev._next = temp
    temp = l._next
    l._next = r._next
    r._next = temp
    temp = l._prev
    l._prev = r._prev
    r._prev = temp

    return
```

list before swap: 4  5  2  7  1  8
list backwards before swap: 8  1  7  2  5  4

I am swapping the node that contains 5 as l, and the node that contains 7 as r.

list after swap: 4  7  2  5  1  8
list backwards after swap: 8  1  7  4

I have tested multiple times with multiple methods, the result is either the same or there is some sort of infinite circular reference going on. What I am thinking is when I change the next pointers, I am already messing up their previous pointers, but don't have concrete proof of that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you aren't changing the `X._next._prev` references...  Also note that you never need a temp variable to swap values in Python: you can just say `X, Y = Y, X`.  Also also note that it would be vastly easier to just swap the *values* of the two nodes, no 'pointer' changes required...

Comment: Hi, i prefer to do the swap with a temp variable since I have to learn other languages in the future that don't have this feature. Moving the data is not an option. I must move the nodes. Thank for the suggestion I will try it out in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `getitem` method that will retrieve a value at an index, and a `setitem` method to update a node at an index. That way, a simple `swap` method can be written by reassigning the values:

```
def check_index(f):
  def wrapper(cls, _val, *args):
    if cls._next is None and _val:
      raise IndexError(f'{_val} exceeds length of deque')
    return f(cls, _val, *args)
  return wrapper

class Deque:
  def __init__(self, _val= None, _previous = None):
     self.value = _val
     self._next, self._previous = None, _previous
  @check_index
  def __getitem__(self, _index):
     return self.value if not _index else self._next[_index-1]
  @check_index
  def __setitem__(self, _index, _val):
     if not _index:
       self.value = _val
     else:
       self._next[_index-1] = _val
  def insert_val(self, _val, _trailing = None):
     if self.value is None:
        self.value = _val
     else:
        if self._next is None:
          self._next = Deque(_val, _trailing)
        else:
          self._next.insert_val(_val, self._next)
  def swap(self, _start, _finish):
    _temp = self[_start]
    self[_start] = self[_finish]
    self[_finish] = _temp
  def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.value}, {str(self._next)}' if self._next is not None else str(self.value)
  def __repr__(self):
     return f'Deque({str(self)})'
```

---

```
d = Deque()
for i in range(10):
  d.insert_val(i)
>>>d
Deque(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
>>>d.swap(2, 6) #swapping the third item with the 7th item
>>>d
Deque(0, 1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: The problem here is you are just switching the values. I want the nodes to be switched. getitem & setitem would not work if the node class has more than one value attribute.

Comment: @znrmrjyzo Swapping the nodes would produce exactly the same output as above if you are still looking for a valid doubly-linked-list, since the `previous` and `next` attributes for the node to be switched would have to point to the `previous` and `next` attributes of the original value it is being swapped with. Can you further clarify what you are trying to accomplish with this deque/doubly-linked-list?

Comment: the thing is, if i just swap value, what if the node class had more value attributes? i would have to swap all of them one by one. switching the nodes would be more efficient.

Comment: i am trying so that node A next points to node B next and vice versa, and node A previous points to node B previois and vice versa. but the code is not working as expected

Comment: @znrmrjyzo How specifically is it not working? Also, if you have multiple attributes, I suggest you use a list or a dictionary.

Comment: i already stated how its not working in my initial question. the previous node reference updates are not working. im not looking for a workaround, this is for me to get a deeper understanding of linked structures